# Why can't I Build and View PdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

```
Could not start Build & View:PdfLaTeX:
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "moderncv".tex.
```

When I try to Build my Project with `F5`,  I get the error above. I do not understand why. The file structure of my project is below:

[image]

I do not understand why I am getting this error right now.

texlive is already installed on my system. Invoking `sudo apt-get install texlive` on my *Ubuntu*, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive is already the newest version (2015.20160320-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-72-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 214 not upgraded.
```

I am currently getting these errors on **TeXstudio**.

When I invoke the command `pdflatex cv_7` within my project folder, I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./cv_7.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(./moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter d
ocument class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xargs/xargs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(./moderncvcompatibility.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/suffix.sty) (./tweaklist.sty))
 (./moderncvstyleclassic.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marvosym/umvs.fd))
(./moderncvcolorpurple.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(./cv_7.aux) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmss.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./cv_7.out) (./cv_7.out) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-mvs.cfg)
<pictures/picture.JPG, id=27, 1183.3008pt x 1135.1208pt>
<use pictures/picture.JPG>
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 56--56


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 80.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 80--80


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 82--82


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 86--86


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 90--90

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./pictures/picture.JPG>]

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 95--95

[2] (./cv_7.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `cv_7.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc
/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmcsc10.pfb></usr/s
hare/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmss10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/publi
c/lm/lmss12.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmss17.pfb></usr/share/
texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmss8.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/l
mssbx10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmsso10.pfb></usr/share/tex
mf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmsso17.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/public/marvosym/marvosym.pfb>
Output written on cv_7.pdf (2 pages, 3521903 bytes).
Transcript written on cv_7.log.
```

Comment: Please tell us more: Which tool on which OS are you using?

Comment: have you installed tex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added more details to the question.

Comment: @MartinSchröder  I added more details to the question.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala can you tell us which editor you are using?

Comment: @samcarter TeXstudio

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Ok, can you do two things? Open a terminal, cd into the folder of your latex project and type `pdflatex cv_7`. Does this work? Is the pdf updated?

Comment: @samcarter, updated the question!

Comment: @Schweinebacke I haven't changed the configuration of Texstudio. This is the first time I am trying to use Texstudio on my new computer. + I am sure I have never tried to set the master file either.

Comment: @Schweinebacke how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Looks good. To change the Master document go to `options->Root document->detect automatically` or change into the tab with cv_7.tex and `options->Root document->set current document explicit as root document`

Comment: @samcarter that fixed it! I got both `moderntex` and `cv7` on my structure list and now I can build the document. Can you please include this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Schweinebacke Would you like to answer? You noticed the wrong file being compiled.

Comment: @samcarter Done, because you've asked. But please, feel free to use my comments to make an answer whenever you like.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main document is `cv_7.tex`, Texstudio obviously uses the wrong root document, because it runs `pdflatex` for `"moderncv".tex` instead of `"cv_7".tex`.

Changing the root document can be done in several ways:

- Open `cv_7.tex` in Texstudio and click select the menu entry `Options` → `Root Document` → `Set Current Document as Explicit Root`. This will set `cv_7.tex` as root document.
- Open `cv_7.tex` in Texstudio and right click to `cv_7.tex` structure view (left side of the Texstudio window) and select `set as explicit root document`. This will set `cv_7.tex` as root document.
- Open `cv_7.tex` in Texstudio and click select the menu entry `Options` → `Root Document` → `Detect Automatically`. This will unset the current root document and switch back to use the current document as root.
- In Texstudio right click to `moderncv.tex` in the structure view (left side of the Texstudio window) and select `remove explicit root document role`. This will unset `moderncv.tex` from being the root document and switch back to use the current document as root.
- Remove an existing *magic comment* from the document. That would be a line like

  ```
  % !TeX root = moderncv.tex
  ```

  Such a line would set `moderncv.tex` a root document and removing the line should reset `moderncv.tex` from being the root document if it has been set by the magic comment only.
- Adding a *magic comment* at the very beginning of the document, in your case:

  ```
  % !TeX root = cv_7.tex
  ```

  This will set `cv_7.tex` as root document, but does not work, if another document has been set as explicit root using the menu or structure view.

Note: You do not need to use all of the described solutions. Try one by one and test, whether or not Texstudio compiles `cv_7.tex`.

See [section 4.1.1, Root Document, in the Texstudio manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#sec:rootdocument) for more information about the root document.